# How to change the point to slide a (cocoa) custom sheet?

Tags: cocoa

I would like to use in my Mac App a mainwindow with a title bar with custom height (like sparrow, twitter app, reader for mac and others).

I´m using https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow for this and it works perfect.

I would like to use also some custom sheets. The problem is that this sheets are open sliding from the bottom of the REAL titlebar that means the middle (more or less) of the new FAKE titlebar (and looks really bad).

Any idea how to change the point the custom sheets have to slide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set an object as the delegate of the `NSWindow` that the sheet is attached to, and implement the `‑window:willPositionSheet:usingRect:` delegate method.

You can then modify the proposed position of the sheet and return a revised `NSRect`.

The rect that you return indicates the position, width and behaviour of the opening animation, it doesn't control the width of the resulting sheet.

Have a look at the [docs about positioning sheets](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/PositioningSheets.html) for more info.